# Some US Xbox 360 games not working on my xbox360 - claiming region lock

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360, region-lock, fifa-13

I have two games: Skyrim and Fifa 13. They are both NTSC-U games but my NTSC-U xbox blocks me from playing the games due to region block.

The xbox was bought in Japan while on a trip there, but at the initial setup the region was set to US because that is where I get my games from.

Other US games (such as Mass Effect 2 and 3, Dead Space, Halo 4, Gears of War, etc) work without any issues. But for these two there seems to be a problem.

The Skyrim is the second copy of the game that I have bought, the previous copy had the same issue (region locked), and I assumed purchasing a new copy would resolve this problem but it's still here.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: AFAIK, the region of an Xbox (or any other game console) is factory set and not affected by user settings on the console, therefore your console is probably NTSC-J, hence why some of the games, specifically those locked to NTSC-U, don't work. I don't own an Xbox 360 so I can't confirm this 100%

Comment: I've just found [this](http://forum.xbox-sky.cc/xbox360_regional_compatibility_guide/) and it looks like you might be right. The games that do work on my console work across the 3 regions...which means I'd have to buy the games from Asia in order to play them on my console.

Comment: @JohnoBoy You should make your comment an answer, because it is 100% correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The region of the Xbox 360 is factory set and not affected by user settings on the console, therefore your console is probably NTSC-J, hence why some of the games, specifically those locked to NTSC-U, don't work.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer! Also found this:[http://forum.xbox-sky.cc/xbox360_regional_compatibility_guide/](http://forum.xbox-sky.cc/xbox360_regional_compatibility_guide/) which provides a list of which games are playable in what regions, this stuff is also available on the Play-Asia.com site. Thanks Again!